# Reading space-separated data with spaces data

Tags: c++, file, text, readline

I'm reading lines from a text file where the data is separated in columns by spaces similar to this:

```
UNITED STATES OF AMERICA           WASHINGTON          9629047   291289535
CHINA                              PEKING              9596960   1273111290
```

I had previously handled similar data using the following code:

```
ifstream readThis("somefile.txt", ios::in);
while (readThis >> country >> capital >> area >> population) {
    // some code...
}
```

This worked fine when the data didn't have spaces (like "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA"). What happens now is that as soon as a space is encountered the data is saved to the next variable (ie. "2UNITED" would go to `country`, "STATES" would go to `capital` and so on). What I'm about to do is what I feel is pretty hack-y so I was hoping they'd be a better way of handling the data. Here's what I think of doing now:

- Read the entire line with `std::getline`.
- Go through the line character by character.
- Store the characters in the proper variable until we've read 2 spaces in a row.
- At this point ignore any whitespace and read until we reach a character.

This method looks more like an exercise from K&R and probably isn't a C++ way of doing this. I should mention that the data is all properly aligned (the "columns" are all the same width). I'm thinking there has to be a way to read "aligned" data properly (basically the opposite of `cout << setw(20) << "Hello" << ...`

Any ideas welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a [regular expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to do that more elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a better method is:
1. read the entire line with `std::getline`.
2. Extract the fields using `std::substr` and the field widths.
3. Trim the field strings as necessary.
4. Process the fields.
5. Repeat at step 1 until the read fails.

Answer (score 0):

*That* is a clear case for regular expressions if I know one ([live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9da2c014e974e8f)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main() {
    std::istringstream i { "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA  WASHINGTON, DC  2233232  23232323\nPOPULAR REPUBLIC OF CHINA  BEIJING  23232323  23232323\nBRAZIL  BRASILIA  232323233  2323323\n" };
    boost::regex r { R"(^(.*?)\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+(\d+)\s\s+(\d+))", boost::regex::perl };
    std::string line;
    while( std::getline(i, line) ) {
        boost::smatch m;
        if( !boost::regex_match(line, m, r) )
            continue;
        auto country = m[1].str();
        auto capital = m[2].str();
        auto area = m[3].str();
        auto pop = m[3].str();
        std::cout << capital << ", " << country << ";\n";
    }
}
```

Notice that

```
#include <regex>
```

and the use of `std::regex`, `std::smatch`, `std::regex_match` only work if you are using `libc++`, the GNU `libstdc++` (up to 4.8) isn't working.